# How to raise a textBox_InsertPlaceChanged event in TextBox at C#?

Tags: c#, wpf, textbox

I couldnt make good question i know,but it is what i could.When user write something in textbox there appear symbol flashing which shows place which will be inserted character.It can be changed by left and right arrow buttons.I want to raise event when it is changed  or something that i can get index of this "symbol".is there any property at textBox for it?

Comment: Possible duplicate [does vs2010 have a caret position changed event for a textbox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4484562/does-vs2008-vs2010-has-a-caret-position-changed-event-in-textbox)

Comment: Don't think it's a duplicate. The other question is ambiguous in terms of the technology it's focusing on (wpf, winforms, webforms)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "symbol" is called a caret. When it's position changes, the `SelectionChanged` event is fired, and you can programmatically retrieve the position using the `CaretIndex` property on the `TextBox`.

You can find more information about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textbox.caretindex.aspx).

Comment: i already found that this is symbol is called caret :)thank you for quick reply

Comment: Turns out I was wrong about no event being raised. I've modified my answer to reflect my newly acquired knowledge :)

Comment: with logic,selection start and caret index must be same when no selection in textbox,is it right?

Comment: i asked this because i need to bind it with property at behind code.But already saw that as caret index,selection start also is not bindable

Comment: Yup, neither of them are DependencyProperties

Comment: then there is only 1 way,i must create own textbox(inherited from textbox) which this have bindable caret index property

Comment: You could use attached properties as well, but my knowledge on those is relatively limited, so I'm not sure if that'd be the best approach.